# character encoding changes in R

Tags: r, character-encoding

I have received some data that contains some Russian characters and has been converted to some encodings like

```
<U+041D>
```

Is there a function to convert these back to UTF-8 so that they will display the characters correctly again?

Comment: You could try enc2utf8() which converts the encoding to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
as.character(parse(text = shQuote(gsub("<U\\+([A-Z0-9]+)>", "\\\\u\\1", "Bl<U+041D>"))))
# [1] "BlН"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10148484)

Comment: `<U+041D>` <=> `Н`. The question was _"Is there a function ... so that they will display the characters correctly again?"_ What's your point?

Comment: Try `x` is a comment. Answers require explanations.

Comment: Is that your opinion, or do the SO rules explicitly say that answers needs explanations, even if the original poster maybe just want's a quick solution to his problem?

Comment: My opinion, but it's not uncommon: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163587/when-to-answer-vs-when-to-just-comment

Personally I strongly recommend explication because this is not a one-on-one forum with OP. Future visitors may have slightly broader interests than did OP, in which case an answer with more meat can potentially answer similar but marginally distinct questions as well.